# Inline assembly with branch

Tags: assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, riscv

I got the following code :

```c
    int *heap_x_test = (int*) malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    heap_x_test[0] =   0x00310033 ; // add  zero,sp,gp
    heap_x_test[1] =   0x008110b3 ; // sll  ra,sp,s0
    heap_x_test[2] =   0x00c00313 ; // li   t1,12
    heap_x_test[3] =   0x00f00493 ; // li   s1,15
    printk("Target adress is 0x%x\n",heap_x_test);
    printk("Code injection is 0x%x\n", heap_x_test[0]);
    __asm__("beq x0, x0, %0" : "i"(heap_x_test));
```

I try to send code inside the heap and make it execute. I use the pmp in a riscv implementation and i want to check if i setup it right to protect the heap.

This specific line of the code doesn't seem to work :

```c
__asm__("beq x0, x0, %0" : "i"(heap_x_test));
```

I tried to modify "i" with "r" and "=r" but it doesn't work either, i also tried a jr instruction with heap_x_test as label in the asm macro but it doesn't seem to work either.
The compiler return :

```
error: output operand constraint lacks '='
   37 |         __asm__("beq x0, x0, %0" : "i"(heap_x_test));
```

Edit :
When i use "=r" it compile but in the objdump of main I don't see the beq instruction :

```
   0x80000ab0 <+0>: addi    sp,sp,-16
   0x80000ab4 <+4>: sw  ra,12(sp)
   0x80000ab8 <+8>: sw  s0,8(sp)
   0x80000abc <+12>:    li  a0,16
   0x80000ac0 <+16>:    jal ra,0x8000782c <malloc>
   0x80000ac4 <+20>:    mv  s0,a0
   0x80000ac8 <+24>:    lui a5,0x310
   0x80000acc <+28>:    addi    a5,a5,51 # 0x310033
   0x80000ad0 <+32>:    sw  a5,0(a0)
   0x80000ad4 <+36>:    lui a5,0x811
   0x80000ad8 <+40>:    addi    a5,a5,179 # 0x8110b3
   0x80000adc <+44>:    sw  a5,4(a0)
   0x80000ae0 <+48>:    lui a5,0xc00
   0x80000ae4 <+52>:    addi    a5,a5,787 # 0xc00313
   0x80000ae8 <+56>:    sw  a5,8(a0)
   0x80000aec <+60>:    lui a5,0xf00
   0x80000af0 <+64>:    addi    a5,a5,1171 # 0xf00493
   0x80000af4 <+68>:    sw  a5,12(a0)
   0x80000af8 <+72>:    mv  a1,a0
   0x80000afc <+76>:    lui a0,0x80008
   0x80000b00 <+80>:    addi    a0,a0,-588 # 0x80007db4
   0x80000b04 <+84>:    jal ra,0x80001340 <printk>
   0x80000b08 <+88>:    lw  a1,0(s0)
   0x80000b0c <+92>:    lui a0,0x80008
   0x80000b10 <+96>:    addi    a0,a0,-564 # 0x80007dcc
   0x80000b14 <+100>:   jal ra,0x80001340 <printk>
   0x80000b18 <+104>:   lw  ra,12(sp)
   0x80000b1c <+108>:   lw  s0,8(sp)
   0x80000b20 <+112>:   addi    sp,sp,16
   0x80000b24 <+116>:   ret
```

If i use volatile to avoid compiler optimisation it output :

```
undefined reference to `a5
```

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 1):

The target of a `beq` or other simple branch instruction needs to be a *label* in the code, not a value.  In general, to jump to code in the heap, you're going to need an *indirect* branch.  On riscv, the only way to do that is with a `jalr` instruction.  Something like:

```
__asm__ volatile("jr %0" :: "r"(heap_x_test));
```

(`jr` being an alias for `jalr` with a fixed `x0` destination)

Comment: It compiles with "=r" and not "r". 
beq to takes a value for the branch since the label is just replace by an adress by the compiler, the only difference is that it takes 12 bits while jalr takes 20 i think.
And it just added ```0x80000b18 <+104>: jr a5``` in the objdump. I still don't know why a5

Comment: I did try this simple stuff ```beq x0, x0, 0x1200``` and it compile, so the problem was probably juste the number of bits used by jalr

Comment: `a5` is the register it is using to hold the pointer to the heap.  `b` instructions can only go to a fixed (pc-relative) address, not a dynamic address.

Comment: @LovisXII and Chris: Also note that if you're going to jump outside of an `asm()` statement, you should follow it with `__builtin_unreachable()` so the compiler knows that, and doesn't defer any work for after the asm statement.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#GotoLabels

Comment: @LovisXII: The other common way to do this is to cast your `malloc` result to a function pointer and call it as a C function. Either way, you need `__builtin___clear_cache(start,end)` to make sure instruction-fetch sees the recent stores (not optimized away as dead stores, and on ISAs without coherent I-cache, whatever flushing is necessary).  [How does \_\_builtin\_\_\_clear\_cache work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/35741814) / [execute binary machine code from C](//stackoverflow.com/q/18476002) / [How do I call hex data stored in an array with inline assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/56213418)

Comment: Oh great answer thanks ! I'm rusing ripe software and I think that's why they are using dummy_function, i never got its use until now ! And I'm working on a custom cpu, my code using running on some kind on simulator, it runs on fpga so I'm not sure I'll need to use __builtin_unreachable(), or maybe I'm wrong ?

Comment: I was just reading again the objdump and a5 will contain the value i store inside my buffer at the end, it won't contain the address of the heap so I don't get it right on how its supposed to be pointed to the heap

Answer (score 0):

With all of what you suggested i finally succeed to write my code, here's a the correction of the code which seems to work just fine :

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <malloc.h>


 void dummy_function(){
    printk("Inside %s\n", __func__);
 }


void main(void)
{
    int buffer[12];
    int *heap_x_test = (int*) malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    heap_x_test[0] =   0x00310033 ; // add  zero,sp,gp
    heap_x_test[1] =   0x008110b3 ; // sll  ra,sp,s0
    heap_x_test[2] =   0x00c00313 ; // li   t1,12
    heap_x_test[3] =   0x00f00493 ; // li   s1,15
    printk("Target adress is 0x%x\n",heap_x_test);
    printk("Code injection is 0x%x\n", heap_x_test[0]);

    void (*dummy_function)()__attribute__((used)) = (void (*)())heap_x_test;
    dummy_function();

}
```

Kind regards

Comment: You're missing `__builtin___clear_cache` between the assignment to `heap_x_test[3]` and the call to `dummy_function()` (the function pointer inside main that shadows the global `dummy_function`; it would be much better to pick a different name since they're actually unrelated).  You're also missing a `ret` in the machine code you store on the heap, so it won't return.  Of course, you overwrite its return address with an `sll` of the stack pointer so a `ret` wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: All i wanted to see was if my pmp will crash the code and I did, programm just stopped after the call of the dummy_function() so not sure to understand why ``__builtin___clear_cache`` have to be used.
The function pointer ``(*dummy_function)`` and the ``dummy_function`` are the same isnt it ?

Comment: Calling `printk` maybe evicts cache enough that the CPU sees your stores, or else it crashes on the `0` bytes they were (probably) originally filled with.  IIRC, RISC-V is careful that `0` isn't a NOP, so it doesn't go past the end of your `heap_x_test` stores and into other garbage.

Comment: Nothing ever calls the `void dummy_function(){ printk(); }` so it's weird to have it in your example.  Main can't see it because you declared a function pointer with the same name.